# Why the tensor product of list of variable change the subscript position in products

Tags: polynomials, tensors

```
{Subscript[g, 1],Subscript[e, 1]}\[TensorProduct]{Subscript[g, 2],Subscript[e, 2]}\[TensorProduct]{Subscript[g, 3],Subscript[e, 3]}
```

I am expecting answer like ...

```
{{{Subscript[g, 1] Subscript[g, 2] Subscript[g, 3], 
 Subscript[g, 1] Subscript[g, 2] Subscript[e, 3]}, { 
 Subscript[g, 1] Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[g, 3], 
 Subscript[g, 1] Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[e, 3] }}, {{Subscript[e, 
 1] Subscript[g, 2] Subscript[g, 3], 
Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[g, 2] Subscript[e, 3] }, {Subscript[e, 1]
  Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[g, 3], 
Subscript[e, 1] Subscript[e, 2] Subscript[e, 3]}}}
```

Why it change the sequence in the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any product gets reordered alphabetically by Mathematica, apparently.  Try entering `g*e` and `e*g`, and you'll see they are both reordered to `e g`, which works just fine when all multiplications are commutative.

If you really want the `g` terms to come before the `e` terms, then you might find some of the solutions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols) to be of use.  Conversely, if you just use `h` or any other letter after `g` in place of `e` then that also solves your problem I think.

Comment: Nice explanation in that link!