# Changing the order of a factor

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I've done:

```
p[x_] := x^2 + x + 1;
roots = Solve[p[x] == 0, x] // ComplexExpand;
roots = roots /. x -> y;
Times @@ (x - y /. roots)
```

Which produces this output:

```
(* (1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x) (1/2 + (I Sqrt[3])/2 + x) *)
```

What can I add so that the output is:

$$\left(x+\frac12+\frac{i\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac12-\frac{i\sqrt3}{2}\right)$$

I did try TraditionalForm.

Comment: There's not much flexibility in terms of reordering.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols

Comment: _Mathematica_ has its own idea about the canonical ordering of terms. Learn to love it.

Comment: Does any of this help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols?lq=1